# How to assign value to set of objects in c#

Tags: c#

I want to be able to assign data to a set of values at a go without using a loop. something like this.

```
transactions.Where(x => x.sender == agent.realId).AllRows.Amount = 625000;
```

without doing something like this

```
var trans = transactions.Where(x => x.sender == agent.realId);
foreach(var t in trans)
{ 
    t.Amount = 625000;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: whats wrong with that?

Comment: What's the source of the data (i.e. where does `transactions` come from)?

Answer (score 3):

You could write an extension method that would allow you to perform an action for each element in the IEnumerable:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in source) { action(item); }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
transactions.Where(x => x.sender == agent.realId).ForEach(t => t.Amount = 625000);
```

Comment: [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) also has this extension.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing is you can't really do it without a loop. If your objective is to make it look more linq-y you can do something similar to this:

```
transactions
    .Where(x => x.sender == agent.realId)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Amount = 625000);
```

But I personally am not a huge fan of this.

First of all, it's still a loop even though it's in a form of a function.

Secondly, even though it does look more like linq, it's really not. Linq operators are all based on functional programming principles, which implies immutability. Here however you want to assign a new value to the `Amount` property which is a mutable operation and therefore going against functional approach.

In conclusion, my advice is to use linq operators when you're doing functional stuff and use loops when you're doing imperative stuff. Shortly - use loops for assignments.

Comment: and also, this actually has two loops, one for ToList, and the other for ForEach. also there is memory allocation because of ToList.